# makefile - iterate and build each file

Tags: gnu-make

I have a list of directories `BUILDS := $(wildcard */)`, each as a Dockerfile.
How do I build each docker file? Obviously, this does not work, but I'm looking for something along the same lines:

`build: $(BUILDS)
    $(DOCKERCMD) $@ -t $(DOCKER_REPO_URL):$(subst /,,$^) --force-rm $^`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details aside, you probably want something on these lines:

**Makefile**

```
BUILDS := a b c

define build_it =
$(1):
    @echo "Building $$@"
    touch $$@
endef

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BUILDS)

$(foreach build,$(BUILDS),$(eval $(call build_it,$(build))))

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILDS)
```

Which runs like:

```
$ make
Building a
touch a
Building b
touch b
Building c
touch c
```

See [8.5 The foreach Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) and
[8.9 The eval Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Mike. I am far from having finishing (those details), but you answered my question exactly.